# procedure or function spAddStudent has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate with SQL Server 2012, When I click save button first time it works fine, but after changing values it shows above mentioned exception. I m failed to solve this problem. please help me.

Thanks

Abdul Muttalib

```
    public int AddStudent(StudentManager studentManager)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCom.CommandText = "spAddStudent";
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", studentManager.Name);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Father", tudentManager.Father);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", tudentManager.Gender);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Religion", studentManager.Religion);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherTongue", studentManager.Tongue);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", studentManager.BrithDate);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", studentManager.StudentClass);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", studentManager.Section);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", studentManager.Shift);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RollNo", studentManager.RollNo);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee", studentManager.Fee);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherOccupation", studentManager.FatherOccupation);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherCNIC", studentManager.Cnic);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddWithValueressRes", studentManager.AddressRes);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneRes", studentManager.PhoneRes);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneOff", studentManager.PhoneOff);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", studentManager.Mobile);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode", studentManager.PostalCode);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", studentManager.Email);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherInfo", studentManager.OtherInfo);
            int i = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            return i;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }           
    }       
}
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91BKg.png)

Comment: I don't see the creating of the SqlCommand.
 But I would suggest an "Using (var sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlCon))" Or calling sqlCom.Dispose() at the end of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by calling sqlCom.Parameters.Clear() at the start of AddStudent to prevent accumulating redundant parameters whenever the method is called. 
Also, using AddWithValue is easy and common, but it can be problematic.